# How do I prove that $f_n(x)=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$ converges pointwise and uniformly?

Tags: uniform-convergence

I'm trying to check if the function sequence $f_n(x)=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$, $x \in (-1,1)$ converges pointwise and uniformly.

If I had the sequence of $g_n(x)= \frac{1-x^n}{1-x^n}$ and $x \in (-1,1)$ i know that $\lim_{n \to \infty } g_n(x) = 1 $ but now how the denominator's $x$ behaves?

Thank you!

Comment: Expand it as a series, use the Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: Pointwisely $x$ is a constant, so $1-x$ behaves as $1-x$.

Comment: Observe that $\frac{1-x^n}{1-x} = \frac{(1-x)\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^k}{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} x^k.$

Comment: I can't understand why people are using this "complicated" identities. $(x^n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converges to $0$, therefore $\left(f_n(x)\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converges to $\dfrac{1}{1-x}$ for every $x$ in $]-1,1[$.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{1 - x^n}{1 - x} = x^{n - 1} + x^{n - 2} + .. + 1$, so $f_n(x)$ is the partial sum of a geometric series. One can then show that $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise and $f_n(x) \rightarrow \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} x^k = \dfrac{1}{1-x}$.

Comment: The convergence isn't uniform on $(-1,1)$, is it? It's certainly uniform on $(-a,a)$ for any $0 \le a < 1$ by the Weierstrass $M$-test, however, since $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ blows up near $1$, there will be problems with uniform convergence. That being said, I haven't actually though about this problem in a very long time so maybe I'm forgetting something.

Comment: Even that isn't quite true I don't think. If you're trying to invoke Dini's Theorem, you need 4 things: you need pointwise convergence, you need the space to be compact, you need the sequence to be monotonic in $n$ and you need the limit to be continuous. Here we don't have a compact space and we don't have monotonicity in $n$.

Answer (score 1):

It converges pointwise to $\frac1{1-x}$ because, for $\lvert x\rvert<1$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} x^n=0$$

**Precisation:** Specifically the denomiantor is *constant in $n$*. So, as much as the pointwise limit is concerned, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1-x^n}{1-x}=\frac{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1-x^n)}{1-x}$$

---

It does not converge uniformly to $\frac1{1-x}$ on $(-1,1)$ because, for all $n$, $$\sup_{x\in(-1,1)}\left\lvert f_n(x)-\frac1{1-x}\right\rvert=\sup_{x\in(-1,1)} \frac{\lvert x\rvert^n}{1-x}\stackrel{x=-1+\frac1n}{\ge}\frac{\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n}{1/n}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\left[\frac {e^{-1}}0\right]=\infty$$